# Is it possible to use Jackson to obtain value from Pojo

Tags: java, json, reflection, jackson

Jackson takes many factors into account when naming a field for serialization into JSON. Is it possible to use those factors in reverse in order to retrieve the value of a field in a pojo based on the name it will have once serialized?

For example, given the bean

```
public class Bean{
    private Bean2 prop;

    @JsonProperty("property")
    public Bean2 getProp();
}
```

Is it possible to get the value of `prop` given only a configured `ObjectMapper`, the string `"property"` and an instance of `Bean`?

I know about reflection, so if I could just get `"prop"` or `"getProp"` I would be pretty much good to go.

Comment: Sure, just list the fields/getter methods of the class and look for the `@JsonProperty`. This sounds awfully roundabout, though, and there might be a better option if you explained more specifically what your use case is.

Comment: You need a good reason to do this for me to approve. One of the points of tools like Jackson is to decouple your logic, which would presumably want to use your POJO objects from the transfer/DTO.

Comment: @chrylis I just used `@JsonProperty` to demonstrate how the field name can be an unexpected value, the annotation won't always be there.

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic the use case is building HAL representations of objects already configured with jackson. So given a pojo and a list of field names (as they will appear serialized) we want to serialize the object as normal, except for the fields with those names. For those fields we want to treat them differently, for which we need their value.

Comment: use custom deserializer  check- http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Comment: I don't see how Jackson is relevant here. You've marked a field with an annotation. Reflect on the fields (or methods), find those that are annotated, and use the object to retrieve their value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the annotation is a jackson annotation, the question is about getting values for objects that will be serialized with jackson (which takes multiple factors besides annotations into account).

Comment: I mean it could be any annotation. How else is Jackson involved (or do you think should be)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the question is "if I have some pojo, (which will later be serialized by jackson), a field name, and an instance of the pojo, can I get the value corresponding to the field name from the pojo". It can't be any annotation, only annotations that jackson will accept one way or another, and it's not just annotations, since names can come from bean methods and other things.

Answer (score 5):

You can de-serialize given JSON String into `Bean` .
Then You can find property using `get()` method of `JsonNode`  and after that you can get value as POJO using `treeToValue()` method.

E.g.

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(bean), JsonNode.class); 

        JsonNode propertyNode = rootNode.get("property");

        Class<?> propertyField = null;

        Field []fields = Bean.class.getDeclaredFields();

         for (Field field : fields){

             //First checks for field name
             if(field.equals("property")){

                 propertyField = field.getType();
                    break;
             }
             else{

                 //checks for annotation name
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(JsonProperty.class) && field.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value().equals("property")) {
                    propertyField = field.getType();
                    break;
                }
                //checks for getters
                else {

                    PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor(field.getName(), Bean.class);

                    Method getMethod = pd.getReadMethod();

                    if (getMethod.isAnnotationPresent(JsonProperty.class) && getMethod.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value().equals("property")) {

                        propertyField = field.getType();

                        break;
                    }
                }
             }
          }


        if(propertyField != null){

            Object o = mapper.treeToValue(propertyNode, propertyField);

        }
```

Comment: This could work, but how can I know the type of `propertyNode`? As stated in the question, I only have a configured ObjectMapper, the string "property" and an instance of `Bean`. So I have no knowledge of the `Bean` class before runtime.

Comment: @kag0 well in that case, you need to use reflection to figure out the field type of that particular name. Check my updated code, in which I have tried to find the type that belongs to particular property name.

Comment: I'm aware that I can use reflection this way (although I didn't know about `PropertyDescriptor`, so that's useful). I want to know if there is specifically a way to use Jackson, instead of doing all the reflection myself. Also, your code would not work if the json field came from a getter with no corresponding java field, or if the field was inherited.

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize the `Bean` into a Json String, then deserialize the same Json String into a Map (just call `ObjectMapper.readValue(JsonString, Map.class)`) and then you can do `Map.get("property")` and you have it. Here is a one-liner solution:

```
String property = ((Map<String, Object>)mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(bean), Map.class)).get("property").toString();
```

Comment: You can actually convert directly to a map using `mapper.convertValue(bean, Map.class)`. But jackson will deserialize object fields as maps. So if `prop` was of type `Bean2`, `mapper.convertValue(bean, Map.class).get("prop")` would return a `Map<String, Object>`. I'm looking to get `prop` as a pojo.